# iPyWidgets FileUpload not working as I expect it

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Im currently trying to load a file in my jupyter notebook, to read it's content.

My Code:

```
file = widgets.FileUpload(
    description= 'Title',
    accept='.csv',
    multiple=False,
)
box = widgets.HBox([file])
display(box)

# New Cell

print(str(file))
```

I run the first cell, after that i use the FileUploader to Upload a .csv File before running the second cell.
I expect the output to be a dict containing the files Context like "content" etc.

A Screenshot of a simpler version:

[image]

Does anyone know that i'm doing wrong?
I also tried every other idea that came to my mind.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, upload a CSV, and it works as intended. Not able to reproduce your error. Currently using ipywidgets version 7.6.5

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing `file.value` instead.

More info here: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#file-upload (You may need to scroll down if your browser doesn't take you directly to that 'File Upload' heading upon clicking the link.)

Comment: already did that, its still an empty dict

Comment: can you upload some screenshots?

Comment: I did, maybe that helps

Comment: OK that is quite odd, which version of ipywidgets are you using? If it's the latest version you migtht want to search the ipywidgets issues: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues?q=fileupload or add a new issue if that doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you very much :) do you have any version in mind, where this is working? i tried 7.5 ,8 and most in between

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way I found to read a CSV file using iPywidgets uploader is to save the content and then read the file using pandas. You may remove the local file afterward.

Try:

```
    try:
        uploaded_file = uploader.value[0]
        name = uploaded_file["name"]
        with open(name, "wb") as fp:
            fp.write(uploaded_file.content)
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), name))
        break
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Comment: I cannot tell from the limited picture the OP supplied if that was what was causing the issue.